# Problems with aligning contents grid-wise

Tags: html, css

Look at this [image]

I'm using `float:left` to align contents of my website grid-wise.

On the left side, the space between the two objects is `24px`, whereas on the right side it's `10px`.

How do I fill up the extra spaces so that both sides can have `10px` margin?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle.net file to see what you have?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you want with just CSS floats unless you make all your panels a fixed height and truncate the content of it's too big.

If you must have different sized boxes, use a JavaScript library like Masonry http://masonry.desandro.com

Comment: Is there no 'simple' alternative? Not even one?

Comment: Masonry is a simple alternative. It's a script tag and one like of JavaScript. Or you can force your boxes to always be the same size.